# HTAccess with multiple variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to structure a mod_rewrite URL but can't seem to get the query strings to work alongside the mod_rewrite rules.

My code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^awards awards.php [L]

RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?order=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?order=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&order=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&order=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees nominees.php [L]              

RewriteRule ^register register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [L]
```

If I remove

```
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then the

```
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?order=$1 [L,QSA]
```

works... I just can't seem to get my head around it!

I'm after:

nominees/average
nominees/accountants
nominees/accountants/average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression is **exactly the same** for both rules, which means the first rule will match and the second rule does absolutely nothing. This applies to each of your sets that are exactly the same. You need some other qualifier to differentiate between the "order" and the "cat" parameter. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^nominees/order/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?order=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/cat/([a-z]*)?$ /nominees.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees/order/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?order=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/cat/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&order=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nominees/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)$ /nominees.php?cat=$1&order=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So there's no way to have nominees/accountants/average AND nominees/average?

Comment: @potts I didn't change the rules at the bottom, if it's `nominees/accountants/average`, it matches the very last rule at the bottom. But how are you supposed to tell the difference between `?order=average` and `?cat=average`? URL looks the same for both.

Comment: `nominees.php/?cat=accountants = /nominees/accountants` and `nominees.php/?order=average = /nominees/average`

Comment: @potts You have to realize these rules work the other way around, so what it matches against is `/nominees/average`, how does it know "average" must be an order and not a cat? Are you going to hardcode every order/cat?

Comment: I see, so is there anyway to get the URLs to be `nominees/accountant/?order=average&page=2`? That would be okay wouldn't it?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to keep the /? `nominees/accountants/?page=2` (at the moment it's removing the /) `nominees/accountants?page=2`

Comment: @potts you can do this if you hardcode every possible cat/order

Comment: It seems when I manually enter the URL `nominees/accountants/?page=2` it redirects to the page, without the forward slash...